# Get metrics of a model deployed with ai-platform from python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-ai-platform

When you deploy a model with AI-Platform, you get to see in the link

`https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/ml.googleapis.com/metrics?project=<my_project_name>`

some performance metrics of the API (or an endpoint in particular) that deploys the ML model, such as latency (response time), how many 200 status code occurred, etc...

I would like to get this information from python instead of having it in the GUI. Is this possible ?
I am reading the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/reference/rest) but I can't seem to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install in Python the client library. After that, you need to set up the authentication, and then start using the client library. You can find a detailed guide in the Google documentation for the Python case [1].

Aside of following the steps in the link, here is a list of the available metrics from AI Platform [2].

Finally, here is more information about the Python Client for Cloud Monitoring API [3].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python

[2] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-aiplatform

[3] https://googleapis.dev/python/monitoring/latest/index.html

Comment: Hi Javier, thank you for your answer. What you describe is the first thing I did while trying to get performance metrics from the ai platform model. However, I can't see, neither in python neither in the gui, the metrics of the ai platform model from cloud monitoring. The link I sent is the only place where I can see the performance metrics on the gui, this is why I am trying to grab them from python